# Split Multi-Line Cell into new rows below

Tags: excel, vba

Tried to use this in VBA which works well. 
However, I would like it to run on the entire column of E and F. 
How would it be possible?

```
Sub SplitText()
    Dim MaxSize As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("E1:F1")
    MaxSize = 0

    For Each cell In rng
        Dim CurrentSize As Integer
        CurrentSize = UBound(Split(cell.Value, vbLf))

        If CurrentSize > MaxSize Then
            MaxSize = CurrentSize
        End If
    Next

    Rows((rng.Row + 1) & ":" & (rng.Row + MaxSize)).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    For Each cell In rng
        Dim SplitText
        SplitText = Split(cell.Value, vbLf)
        cell.Resize(UBound(SplitText) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(SplitText)
    Next

End Sub
```

[image: This is an example]

Comment: You do it by inserting rows and working from the bottom to the top.

Comment: What if E2 has more 'multi-lines' that F2? Are there supposed to be blanks in column F or is the data mismatched?

Comment: Would a check if current cell actually is merged help too?

Comment: E2 would have the same number of rows in the cell as F2.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data with expected result (inside your original question with an edit)?

Comment: I have added an image link. Hope that helps.

Comment: Whenever you post the screenshot of your data, always include the row# and column headers. That way it is helpful to visualize where your data is placed on the sheet as any VBA code will rely on that.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the screenshot.

Comment: No. You misunderstood what I said. See this example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UXyBCpjPgssdLGqd2T11IbiW6LBepJnv

Comment: Your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop from the bottom to the top that inserts.

```
Sub splitMany()

    Dim i As Long, valE As Variant, valF As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet13")

        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1
            valE = Split(.Cells(i, "E").Value2, Chr(10))
            valF = Split(.Cells(i, "F").Value2, Chr(10))
            If UBound(valE) > 0 Or UBound(valF) > 0 Then
                .Cells(i, "E").Resize(Application.Max(UBound(valE), UBound(valF)), 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
                .Cells(i, "E").Resize(UBound(valE) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(valE)
                .Cells(i, "F").Resize(UBound(valF) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(valF)
            End If
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your original data into a VBA array, and created each line as an element of a collection. If you have a lot of data, this will be faster than multiple reads/writes to/from the worksheet.

The notes in the code are important.  As written, the results will be placed on a different worksheet, but you can overwrite the original by changing the `wsRes` and `rRes` locations.

There is a check to ensure that there are the same number of "lines" in the `Colour` and `Name of Guest(s)` columns, else the routine will not complete.  If you want something else to happen, you will need to specify it.

There is a formatting section where you can do pretty much what you like.

```
Option Explicit
Sub reOrganize()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim col As Collection
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim V(1 To 6), V1, V2, W

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")

'If want to overwrite original data, just change below to reflect
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Cells.Find(what:="S/N", after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, _
        lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).CurrentRegion
End With

'Collect the data
Set col = New Collection
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc)
    V1 = Split(vSrc(I, 5), vbLf)
    V2 = Split(vSrc(I, 6), vbLf)
        If UBound(V1) <> UBound(V2) Then
            MsgBox "Color not matching with guest on line " & I
            Exit Sub
        End If
    For J = 0 To UBound(V1)
        V(1) = vSrc(I, 1)
        V(2) = vSrc(I, 2)
        V(3) = vSrc(I, 3)
        V(4) = vSrc(I, 4)
        V(5) = V1(J)
        V(6) = V2(J)
        col.Add V
    Next J
Next I

ReDim vRes(0 To col.Count, 1 To 6)

'Headers
For J = 1 To UBound(vRes, 2)
    vRes(0, J) = vSrc(1, J)
Next J

'data
I = 0
For Each W In col
    I = I + 1
    For J = 1 To 6
        vRes(I, J) = W(J)
    Next J
Next W

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes

'Formatting stuff
'Modify however you like
 .Style = "Output"
    With .Rows(1).Font
        .Size = .Size + 2
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    With .Offset(rowoffset:=1).Resize(rowsize:=.Rows.Count - 1)
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rRes.Cells(2, 1).Address(False, False) & "=" & rRes.Cells(1, 1).Address(False, False)
        .FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = rRes.Cells(2, 1).Interior.Color
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

**Original Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]